# Converted website into a Progressive Web App (PWA ) not working on Edge

Tags: html, forms, microsoft-edge, progressive-web-apps

"Turn your website into a Progressive Web App", they said.

"It will be easy", they said.

So I did.

My site (www.romanorum.com.au) is fairly traditional HTML forms, dynamic web pages etc using razor. I followed the bouncing ball, made my site HTTPS, downloaded the service worker scripts, ran Lighthouse etc. Of course my dynamic web pages continually hit errors using Cache First. I changed it to Server First, and everything seemed fine ... but now I notice that any page that posts a html form (such as my Search screen or Checkout page) receives a "Cannot find your page" error on Edge. These pages continue to work perfectly fine in Chrome and even Internet Explorer, but Edge consistently has never brought across form data since I converted it to a PWA, and errors instead.

The forms are submitted using native HTML5, I use as least javascript I can on the site. What could I have done wrong?

EDIT: Here is the service worker script I added from PWABuilder, the posting cshtml files have not been changed as used to work beautifully in Chrome/IE and Edge. I'm thinking my site is not really a PWA ...

```js
var CACHE = 'pwabuilder-precache';
var precacheFiles = [
      /* Add an array of files to precache for your app */
    ];

//Install stage sets up the cache-array to configure pre-cache content
self.addEventListener('install', function(evt) {
  console.log('[PWA Builder] The service worker is being installed.');
  evt.waitUntil(precache().then(function() {
    console.log('[PWA Builder] Skip waiting on install');
    return self.skipWaiting();
  }));
});


//allow sw to control of current page
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log('[PWA Builder] Claiming clients for current page');
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(evt) {
  console.log('[PWA Builder] The service worker is serving the asset.'+ evt.request.url);
  evt.respondWith(fromServer(evt.request).catch(fromCache(evt.request)));
  evt.waitUntil(update(evt.request));
});


function precache() {
  return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
    return cache.addAll(precacheFiles);
  });
}

function fromCache(request) {
  //we pull files from the cache first thing so we can show them fast
  return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
    return cache.match(request).then(function (matching) {
      return matching || Promise.reject('no-match');
    });
  });
}

function update(request) {
  //this is where we call the server to get the newest version of the 
  //file to use the next time we show view
  return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
    return fetch(request).then(function (response) {
      return cache.put(request, response);
    });
  });
}

function fromServer(request){
  //this is the fallback if it is not in the cache to go to the server and get it
  return fetch(request).then(function(response){ return response});
}
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: I provided the URL (not as link you will notice) for background only, and I cannot figure out what code to post. Since the problem only appears in Edge and only after I PWA-ed it - no page code was changed. I should also mention the forms post fine on Edge if InPrivate browsing is used. I will add the PWA script code to my question since that it is the only code that was added, but it was autogenerated by the PWA builder site.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me on Android Edge. I got to the Checkout screen with no issues. Have you been testing in the same browser as you develop? If so, perhaps 1) make sure you have totally cleared out everything from the cache 2) have someone else try in Edge that has not been there yet.

Comment: Interesting. Yes I did originally test on my developing machine, and I too automatically assumed it was the cache. Cleared all my caches and tried again. No luck. Also tested on 2 other machines that had not yet been to the site. In all cases Chrome worked fine, Edge did not (unless it was InPrivate).

Answer (score 1):

did you implement all the required stuff:

- A web manifest, with the correct fields filled in
- The website to be served from a secure (HTTPS) domain
- An icon to represent the app on the device
- A service worker registered, to make the app work offline (this is required only by Chrome for Android currently)

From this website: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Progressive/Installable_PWAs

Answer (score 0):

There are some issue i faced with Edge. Then i came to know there is a dependency with Windows build version, service worker and PWA will work seemlesly in Windows 10 **RS4** all features will be available in **RS5** only features like **Quota API** etc.